# It says oracle.jdbc does not exist and cannot be imported

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I wanted to connect my java program with oracle. JDK version is 1.7. And, Oracle has also been installed and the PATH and CLASSPATH has also been set for these correctly. Now, for jdbc, I put in:
CLASSPATH

```
D:\app\Ratish\product\11.1.0\db_1\jdbc\lib\ojdbc6.jar
```

I tried putting CLASSPATH under system and user variables too (under Environment Variables).
But, in eclipse, i don't see anything to import oracle.jdbc. jdbc package is not present.
Any solutions?

Comment: right click the project folder and go to `build path` then do `configure build path` and click on add external jars

Answer (score 1):

Add the jar for called ojdbc6.jar in the build path of your project and then check.

Answer (score -2):

javac -cp .;D:\app\Ratish\product\11.1.0\db_1\jdbc\lib\ojdbc6.jar ...